# Bedeutung von "unser beider gemeinsame Zukunft"

Tags: meaning, difference

[Dem Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/unser) zufolge kann man sagen

> unser beider gemeinsame Zukunft

was ins Englische als "our common future" übersetzt wird. Ich verstehe nicht, was der Unterschied zwischen diesem und

> unser**e** gemeinsame Zukunft

ist. Was ist eigentlich der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Versionen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*unser beider* ist der Genitiv von *wir beide*. Im heutigen Sprachgebrauch versucht man solche umständlichen Konstruktionen jedoch zu vermeiden und drückt Zugehörigkeit entweder mit *von* oder einem einzelnen Possessivpronomen aus. Solche Ausdrücke sind häufig in älteren Texten, insbesondere in wortgetreuen lateinischen Übersetzungen und auch Bibeltexten anzutreffen und werden in gebildeten Kreisen als Redewendung immer noch gelegentlich benutzt.

Weitere Beispiele (auch auf den Duden-Seiten zu den einzelnen Pronomen zu finden):

> Ich gedenke *deiner* = Ich denke an dich
>   zu *unser aller* Wohl = Zum
>   Wohl von uns allen
>   Erinnerst du dich *meiner*? = Erinnerst du dich an mich?
>   Vater unser