# Possessivpromomen with all-

Tags: interrogative

In Lord of the Rings, Boromir says to Frodo:

> Du bestimmst unser **aller** Schicksal.

I don't understand from a grammatical point of view how "aller" is constructed here. Why shouldn't be "Du bestimmst unser **alles** Schicksal."?

Comment: Same topic, but in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/18298/35111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wir alle" ist eine Bestärkung des einfachen 'wir', die nochmal betont, dass wirklich jeder einzelne der genannten Gruppe ohne Ausnahme eingeschlossen ist, mitmacht oder betroffen ist. Ähnlich lässt sich das auch mit 'ihr alle' und 'sie alle' konstruieren. Das wird dann ganz normal dekliniert:

- Nominativ: Wir alle gehen nach Hause.
- Genitiv: Unser aller Haus steht auf einem Hügel
- Dativ: Uns allen wird dort heute Abend köstliches
  Essen gereicht.
- Akkusativ (und Genitiv): Denn uns alle wird man unser aller Geburtstag wegen dort heute feiern.

Um beim ursprünglichen Satz zu bleiben:

"Du bestimmst unser aller Schicksal" heißt soviel wie "Das Schicksal einer jeden Person der Gruppe wird von dem Subjekt 'Du' bestimmt."

Diese Aussage ist zu unterscheiden von dem ähnlichen Satz "Du bestimmst all unser Schicksal". Das ist bedeutungsgleich mit "Du bestimmst unser gesamtes Schicksal".
Im Format "all (Possesivpronomen) (Akkusativ-Objekt)" ist es eine feste Wortstellung wie bspw. "all mein Zeug" (=mein gesamtes Zeug), "All(e) Deine Bücher" (=Jedes Deiner Bücher), etc. Ich sehe nicht wie man diese Form in den Genitiv setzen könnte; Konstruktionen im Nominativ, Dativ und Akkusativ lassen sich bilden.

Nochmal zum ursprünglichen Satz, besonders zum Wort 'alle' als Mengenangabe:

Das Wort 'alle' kann sich nur auf Mengen von Dingen oder Lebewesen beziehen, die *zählbar* sind. Darum ist ein Satz nicht formulierbar bei dem sich 'alle' auf Schicksal bezieht (denn das ist nicht zählbar). Da muss man - wie oben hier geschrieben - ein anderes Adjektiv wie 'gesamtes' wählen.

Comment: Wow. Danke Dir!!!

Comment: Was ist, wenn ich damit ein weibliches Wort benutze? Zum Beispiel, Mutter.
Wie wird das geschrieben? Unser aller Mutter oder *Unsere* aller Mutter?

Comment: Unser aller Mutter (wir haben alle die selbe Mutter). Unser aller Mütter. (die Mutter jeder einzelnen Person - aber verschiedene Mütter).

Answer (score 1):

*Unser aller* simply is the Genitive of *wir alle*

Comment: Can you expand on this? Is it originally: Das Schicksal unser aller? This is the first time I have seen such use of "unser" as genitive. I thought "unserer" was the grammatically correct one.